# scrapy: multi fields in one page and call different callbacks

Tags: callback, scrapy

In one page, I want to crawl two links, and go into each link to crawl some information, and then collect them in one item, my code is:

```cs
 def parse(self, response):

    a = '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[position()>1]/ul/li/a/'
    # function query returns HtmlXPathSelector(response).select(xpath).extract()
    song_names = query(a + 'text()', response)
    song_links = query(a + '@href', response)

    for name, link in izip(song_names, song_links):
        yield Request(
            url=self.host + link,
            meta={'item': BdmmsItem(singer=name)},
            callback=self.parse_single_song)


def parse_single_song(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']

    album_link = query('a[contains(@href, "/album/")]/@href', response)[0]
    lrc_link = query('//a[@lyricdata]/@lyricdata', response)[0]

    # here, i want to go into the two different page to get different information
    if lrc_link:
        yield Request(
            url=lrc_link[0],
            meta={'item': item},
            callback=self.parse_lrc)
    if album_link:
        yield Request(
            url=album_link[0],
            meta={'item': item},
            callback=self.parse_album)
    # if use urllib2, but how do that in scrapy
    '''
    item['lrc'] = urllib2.urlopen(lrc_link).read()
    item['album'] = some_other_func(urllib2.urlopen(album_link).read())
    '''

def parse_lrc(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['lrc'] = response.body
    yield item

def parse_album(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['album'] = query('div[@id="album-info"]', response)
    yield item
```

It will generate two items. How do I do it to make the information generated in one item?.

Comment: Have you tried the example from [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But that not what I want. I have to handle **two different callbacks** in the **different pages**, see the code above. The example is first crawling page1 then call the parse_page2, but in my case, the two are not in order and needn't pass arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def parse_single_song(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']

    album_link = query('a[contains(@href, "/album/")]/@href', response)[0]
    lrc_link = query('//a[@lyricdata]/@lyricdata', response)[0]

    if album_link:
        meta={'item': item}
        if lrc_link:
            meta['lrc_link'] = lrc_link[0]

        yield Request(
            url=album_link[0],
            meta={'item': item},
            callback=self.parse_album)

def parse_album(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['album'] = query('div[@id="album-info"]', response)

    lrc_link = response.meta.get('lrc_link')
    if lrc_link:
        yield Request(
            url=lrc_link,
            meta={'item': item},
            callback=self.parse_lrc)
    else:
        yield item

def parse_lrc(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['lrc'] = response.body
    yield item
```

It will not work if there is no album link, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this may be a solution. As you said, if there is no album link, lrc is not crawled. What's worse, except album and lrc, I have more other links shoud be crawled, so maybe I should write more than one spiders to acheve ths.

Comment: I think there is a solution using the technique in the answer. Keep all additional links in `request.meta['links']` and make method `generate_next_request(response)` which will look for the links and return a request with corresponding callback or an item if there are no links left. So in `parse_single_song` you will have `yield self.generate_next_request(response)`. And the same in `parse_album` and `parse_lrc`